# How to obtain elements from String separated by commas Java

Tags: java, string, parsing

I'm trying to obtain the values of a String, which is separated by commas.

something like this: `String str = "item1, item2,0 item3, item4, 0 item5 ...."`
This strange String it's because I have a KML that I take the coordinates of a polygon parsing the kml. Example:
`<coordinates>
    2.18954459419779,41.40492402705473,0 2.189651379989959,41.40491712193686,0 2.189993453581252,41.40464878075789, ....`

What i done to separate it, is:

```
 List<String> items = Arrays.asList(str.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
```

But I don't know how to make that this 0 disappears o put a comma between the 0 and the next number.

How can I do it?

---

**Edit: Solution**

Testing the answers, what it works perfect to my problem is this solution:

```
String[] str_solution = str.split("\\s*,0?\\s*");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String data= "2.18954459419779,41.40492402705473,0 2.189651379989959,41.40491712193686,0 2.189993453581252,41.40464878075789,43.9919";
        String[] dtx = data.split(",");
        for (int j = 0; j < dtx.length; j++) {
            if(dtx[j].indexOf(' ')>=0) dtx[j] = dtx[j].split(" ")[1];   
            System.out.println("data["+j+"]="+dtx[j]);
        }
    }

}
```

Result

```
data[0]=2.18954459419779
data[1]=41.40492402705473
data[2]=2.189651379989959
data[3]=41.40491712193686
data[4]=2.189993453581252
data[5]=41.40464878075789
data[6]=43.9919
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add the optional zero to the split pattern

```
"\\s*,0?\\s*"
```

If it's there it will be splitted with the rest, if not it'll just be ignored.

Comment: Yeah, that should consider even more cases, nice catch

Comment: Thats Perfect!, it separates all "double" numbers, and ignore the 0's  . 

Lot of thanks to both ;)

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following code

```
String a = "item1, item2,0 item3, item4, 0 item5";
String[] arr = a.split(",|,0|, 0|, 0 |")
```

This will match ',0'   ', 0'  and ' , 0 ' and will split accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

use the method split from the String

an example that i have tested:

```
  String contenido = "item1,item2,item3";
    String[] palabras;

    palabras = contenido.split(",");

    for(int i = 0; i < palabras.length; i++){
        System.out.println(palabras[i]+ " ");
    }
```